# Pyspark "repeat" function error: Column not callable

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to do a simple calculation inside a select statement like so:

```
for d in dataframes:
    d = d.select(
      'request_timestamp',
      'shard_id',
      'account_id',
      repeat(lit('1'), (13 - length('account_id').cast(IntegerType()))).alias('custom'))
    d.show()
```

The `repeat` function is returning the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-07f1c7fd01f2> in <module>()
     56       'account_id',
     57 #       length('account_id').alias('len'))
---> 58       repeat(lit('1'), length('account_id').cast(IntegerType())).alias('padding'))
     59     d.show()

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py in repeat(col, n)
   1419     """
   1420     sc = SparkContext._active_spark_context
-> 1421     return Column(sc._jvm.functions.repeat(_to_java_column(col), n))
   1422 
   1423 

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1122 
   1123     def __call__(self, *args):
-> 1124         args_command, temp_args = self._build_args(*args)
   1125 
   1126         command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in _build_args(self, *args)
   1086     def _build_args(self, *args):
   1087         if self.converters is not None and len(self.converters) > 0:
-> 1088             (new_args, temp_args) = self._get_args(args)
   1089         else:
   1090             new_args = args

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in _get_args(self, args)
   1073                 for converter in self.gateway_client.converters:
   1074                     if converter.can_convert(arg):
-> 1075                         temp_arg = converter.convert(arg, self.gateway_client)
   1076                         temp_args.append(temp_arg)
   1077                         new_args.append(temp_arg)

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/java_collections.py in convert(self, object, gateway_client)
    510         HashMap = JavaClass("java.util.HashMap", gateway_client)
    511         java_map = HashMap()
--> 512         for key in object.keys():
    513             java_map[key] = object[key]
    514         return java_map

TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

I know this could be done easily with a `udf`, but I would like to understand why I'm unable to make this work even though I'm casting it to an `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

Spark's `repeat` can handle only plain integer as a second parameter. But Hive's `repeat` can handle calculations and you can use this with `expr` like this:

```
df.select(expr('repeat(1, 13 - length(account_id))').alias('custom'))
```